# taglib-ruby and resource balancing (freeing file handles)?

Tags: ruby, id3, id3-tag, taglib-ruby

Friends,

I am trying to processing a huge amount of audio files using a *Ruby* (1.9.3) script by scanning their *ID3-Tags* using the pretty fast `taglib-ruby` (0.2.1 via Gem-Server) library.

Here is a part of my code, while `audio` contains the full file path in a Ruby-String:

```
begin 
  file_ref = TagLib::FileRef.new(audio) 
  unless file_ref.tag.nil? 
     unless file_ref.tag.artist.nil? or file_ref.tag.title.nil?
       …
     end
  end
ensure
 file_ref = nil
end
```

Then I get into trouble nearly at the end of the processing. *TagLib* is complaining about missing read permissions and `FileUtils.mv` is not longer able to move file afterwards. This is probably the case, because my script does not free file handles *TagLib* is eating while processing.

Unfortunalty *I don not found a certain Ruby method* in `taglib-ruby` API, which eventually call one or better both of *TagLibs* C-functions:

```
taglib_tag_free_strings();
taglib_file_free(file);
```

`libmagic` Ruby bindings for instance provide a `close`-Method within its `Magic` class, so that freeing whithin ensure blocks will work.

Am I just missing the correct Ruby method for `taglib-ruby` or is it missing at the moment? Is there another way of freeing file handles acquired via Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are in fact using [taglib-ruby](https://github.com/robinst/taglib-ruby), not the old [ruby-taglib](http://www.hakubi.us/ruby-taglib/). If you're using taglib-ruby, FileRef (and other ::File classes) have an explicit `close` method since version 0.3.0, see [API documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/taglib-ruby/0.3.1/TagLib/FileRef#close-instance_method).

**Update:** Since 0.4.0, an even better solution is to use the `open` class method, which takes a block and handles the closing automatically for you after the block is run. See [documentation of open](http://rubydoc.info/gems/taglib-ruby/TagLib/FileRef#open-class_method). An example:

```
TagLib::FileRef.open(file_name) do |file|
  tag = file.tag
  # do things with tag
end
```